# Why does my script, which aims to remove gravity when the game starts, not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a script in Unity wherein the gravity will go to zero when the game starts. The problem is, the gravity was still there after I launched the game.

This is for a Unity3D game. I've already tried to change the variable name, add `using System;` and moved my script to the top of the Rigidbody component, but none of these things worked.

```
public class PlayerGrav : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I expected the gravity to be removed when the game launches, but in the actual output the gravity still remained, and the cube still fell downwards.

Comment: That is strange are you sure you are dragging the correct object to public field?

Comment: What to you mean by "moved my script to the top of the Rigidbody component"? Maybe your script is attached to the gameObject with a rigidbody? if so you should access Rigidbody from gameObject: gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;

Comment: it might get a velocity from before the call ... you could try to additionally set `rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;` you also could set the global gravity using `Physics.gravity = Vector3.zero;` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-gravity.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new scene
2. create a `new cube`
3. add `rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` to your start function in your PlayerGrav script
4. attach your PlayerGrav script to the `new cube`
5. Hit play, and take look at the "use gravity" property from your `new cube`'s inspector window (make sure the inspector isn't locked to other game object)

If the above tryout succeeds, then you need to check the other code/objects in your original scene. If there are massive other objects in your original scene, then I will suggest disable other objects first, and re-enable them back group by group to see which object/monobhevaiour is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I looked forever trying to find an answer to this. I am new to unity so it took me a long time to figure this out but I am using a Rigidbody 2d so this is what worked for me

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 0;
```